# Can my RPi3 running Raspbian be used to flash DD-WRT on to a compatible router

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sd-card, firmware

I have a Netgear router that is compatible to flash DD-WRT. I have read you can use mac windows or linux. I only have a RPi3 no other computers. Will my Rpi3 work for this? I am running the latest Rasbian and have a 16G sd card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't specify the router, I'll give you the generic answer:

Assuming you're running a mainstream distribution (like Raspbian), a RasPi is for all intents and purposes a Linux PC (just running on an ARM chip instead of, say, an Intel one).

DD-WRT's methods of upgrade in general (web browser, TFTP) will work fine on a RasPi.  Unless your router has a really weird binary-only client of some sort (that happens to be available for Win/Mac/Lin), you'll be fine.

I don't have any experience with Win 10 on a RasPi 3, but I imagine this will hold true here as well.

Comment: Great thank you. Your comment about Rasp-pi running the ARM chip rather than Intel like on a PC is very helpful. way better than a yes it can or no it cant answer I was expecting.  FYI the router is Netgear WNR3500 L

Comment: Two things make me a bit nervous about this router (first, see http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNR3500L): 1. The DD-WRT guys say that v 1 of this router is supported, but v 2 is still being worked on (make sure you have the right one).  2. They mention specifically using IE to upgrade this router on the first pass.  I don't know if that's them being lazy in docs, or if NG has a stupid UI that only works properly with IE.  My guess is you're still fine, but proceed with caution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from any OS, you need just a file upload compatible browser (all existing browsers). Connect to your router (wi-fi, lan), open web browser, type IP address of your router, login, go to the menu with firmware update interface, select DD-WRT firmware file and press upload button.